# How to unify authentication in complex legacy application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, asp-classic, active-directory

Let me start by saying I'm researching ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 and looking at retro-fitting this into our legacy application. Think 10+ years old, substantial amounts of Classic ASP remaining which we're slowly migrating away from.

We have the following:

- Classic ASP
- .NET Web Forms
- .NET Web Service ASMX files
- .NET Web API
- SRS2012 with Custom Authentication

By customising each of these, we've been able to share a single username/password authentication mechanism to give a form of Single Sign On (SSO) across our suite of applications.

We need to upgrade this and I want a solution that involves as little "roll your own" code as possible.

We need:

- Contemporary password hashing/salting scheme, ASP.NET Identity's PBKDF2 is attractive
- Support for SSO from the private networks of end-users running Active Directory, probably on Windows 2008/2012 servers. We will have the cooperation of IT, and a desire to be secure enough to pass an external security audit without requiring big investment for end-user infrastructure.
- We have a primitive SSO we implemented functional now, running some of our assemblies on several customers' local IIS servers, but need to upgrade it to meet contemporary standards.
- Support for legacy functionality, need to be able to integrate with Classic ASP and SSRS, which I believe in Native Mode only supports .NET 2.0 app pools.

I'm reasonably comfortable with what our application needs to do regarding authentication, password management and authorization, having got some good info on ASP.NET Identity and experience with our current architecture.

I'm in the dark on the most lightweight way to implement contemporary SSO that plays nicely with Active Directory and ASP.NET Identity. Do clients need ADFS? Do we need some self-hosted component e.g. Thinktecture IdentityServer? Our own SAML implementation? OAuth2? OpenId?

By virtue of our ASP.NET Web API, we already have some OAuth2 authentication happening using bearer tokens, but it's not widespread

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sort of. It's still pretty rudimentary but we implemented ASP.NET Identity to get PBKDF2 hashing. We replaced our roll-your-own SSO with SAML 2.0 using ComponentSpace. Clients could then SSO using ADFS. To integrate with SSRS and Classic ASP, we used our own session token stored in a cookie. If I were revisiting this, I'd be going down the OpenID Connect and Azure AD path too.

Comment: Thanks! I started looking at OIDC as well and though about using IdentityServer4, but decided it was overkill in my situation (Classic ASP + ASP.NET MVC + React) and just used JwtBearerAuth and created my own JWTs.